# How to use firefox focus to open a url when use intent?

Tags: android, firefox, android-intent

I tried write a app for open a special url use "intent". But I want to use firefox focus to open it. How to use firefox focus to open a url when use intent? And I don't know the component name of firefox focus.

public class MainActivity_EmbedLink extends AppCompatActivity {

```
// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__embed_link);

    String url = "http://123.com ";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: And what if the user does not have that particular app installed?

Comment: any updates on how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with Tasker following the screenshot.

I am sure you can convert the same to code. 
[image: set name][image: set app name]